# Javascript: JSON key values not updating on request

Tags: javascript

I'd like to update my `JSON` value based on selection.

So for that I have simply update my json value as `data.childShow = true`.

[image]

Now as per the screenshot on line no 78 it's actual value is `false` and after updating it's value to `true` ( ref line no 84 ) and it shows as value updated on line no 85 but when i expand that console object it shows as `false`.

***So, why the values are differing when open the object on console log ?***

Screenshot while not opening object of line no 85
[image]

P.S: Before raising this question I have already tried [this](http://playcode.io/625700) demo, but it is not working in my actual application so that i raised this question.

Comment: title says angularjs tag says angular. What are you refering to ? Also what does this have to to with angular/angularjs anyways. Looks like a javascript question.

Comment: Yes it is JS question, i have used in angular v6 so i mentioned over here for just additional information.

Answer (score -1):

Try this thing in console it might solve your confusion. Add an `object` like `let data = { childShow: false }`. Then log it in console. **Do not expand right now**. Now change the value of `data.x = true;` in expanded value but it also has `childShow=false` in first line. **Now expand console log value**. You can see it is displaying `childShow = true`. So it might be fetching current values when we **expand**.

You can also log `childShow` and check what exactly values hold by `data.childShow`. Like in below snippet. It will show you when you do `console.log(data.childShow);` first time it will show `false` and second time it will show `true` which is as `expected`.

Try with below like. `1.` **Open console of browser**. `2.` Click on Run Code Snippet. `3.` Expand object in console.

```js
const data = {
  childShow: false,
}
console.log(data);
console.log(data.childShow); // Output false

data.childShow = true;

console.log(data);
console.log(data.childShow); // Output true
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but it is not working in my actual application so that i raised this question.  https://playcode.io/625700/

Comment: I already know this things but it is not working in my application that is the only concern and you can clearly see in the attached screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible in your case that it might reset value from `angular` `view` to `false`?

Comment: In view i have just applied this condition `<ul *ngIf="data.childShow === true">`