# How are objects handled in JS async programming? Impact of delete-function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a problem with JS and hope someone could help.

**My Goal with this snippet:** Creating an object which contains data of multiple endpoints of an api.

**My Issue:** When I console.log the whole object all properties generated by the functions in the Promise are missing. When i try to access it directly through the property it works. View the browser-output for better understanding...

**How can this even work?**

```
  var tickets = (await app.$api.get('/ticket')).data.result;
  var promisses = [];
  for (const key in tickets) {
    promisses.push(Promise.all([
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/file`).then(response => {tickets[key].files = response.data.result; console.log("X")}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/field`).then(response => {tickets[key].fields = response.data.result}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/group`).then(response => {tickets[key].groups = response.data.result}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/user`).then(response => {tickets[key].users = response.data.result}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/work`).then(response => {tickets[key].work = response.data.result}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/sign`).then(response => {tickets[key].signs = response.data.result}),
      ]));
  }
  await Promise.all(promisses);
  console.log(tickets[0]);
  console.log(tickets[0].fields);
```

[image: Browser-Output: Tested with Microsoft Edge, Chrome, Firefox]

**Edit:** All Properties, not only the fields property are affected.

Comment: why are you pushing an promise all in an array and then in an promise all?

Comment: to get used of the async functionality of js and perform these request in "parallel" and not in a special order and wait until the request before finished until i make the next one

Comment: so you trying to achieve a nested promise.all ?

Comment: i think i know, what you mean... its useless to use nested promisses... you can also pus each promise to the promisses-array

Comment: can you explain what I'm looking at in the console screenshot?

Comment: you see 3 outputs here:
1. console.log("X") from an api-call to validate it was fullfilled
2. the console.log(tickets[0])
3. the console.log(tickets[0].fields)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i've found an solution, but not an answer.

In a function, which is executed **after** the code-snippet a **delete ticket.fields** is used.
Does a delete- function impacts the execution before itself get executed?

*The following code-snippet is working: the original code was with included delete-functions...*

```
function validateTicket(ticket) {
  if (ticket.fields) {
    ticket.fields.forEach(validateTicketField);
    // delete ticket.fields;
  } else throw new Error('MISSING_PARAMETER(fields)');
  if (ticket.files) {
    ticket.files.forEach(validateTicketFile);
    // delete ticket.files;
  } else throw new Error('MISSING_PARAMETER(files)');
  if (ticket.groups) {
    ticket.groups.forEach(validateTicketGroup);
    // delete ticket.groups;
  } else throw new Error('MISSING_PARAMETER(groups)');
  if (ticket.users) {
    ticket.users.forEach(validateTicketUser);
    // delete ticket.users;
  } else throw new Error('MISSING_PARAMETER(users)');
  if (ticket.work) {
    ticket.work.forEach(validateTicketWork);
    // delete ticket.work;
  } else throw new Error('MISSING_PARAMETER(work)');
  if (ticket.signs) {
    ticket.signs.forEach(validateTicketSign);
    // delete ticket.signs;
  } else throw new Error('MISSING_PARAMETER(signs)');
  // TODO: check Ticket Headdata
}
  var tickets = (await app.$api.get('/ticket')).data.result;
  var promisses = [];
  for (const key in tickets) {
    promisses.push(...[
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/file`).then(response => {tickets[key].files = response.data.result; console.log("X")}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/field`).then(response => {tickets[key].fields = response.data.result}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/group`).then(response => {tickets[key].groups = response.data.result}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/user`).then(response => {tickets[key].users = response.data.result}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/work`).then(response => {tickets[key].work = response.data.result}),
        app.$api.get(`ticket/${tickets[key].id}/sign`).then(response => {tickets[key].signs = response.data.result}),
      ]);
  }
  await Promise.all(promisses);
  console.log(tickets[0]);
  console.log(tickets[0].fields);
  tickets.forEach(validateTicket);
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62548305/9695286. In `console.log` it `logs` the `object`. But it will only retrieve and display all `properties` when you expand object values.

Answer (score -1):

> Check this stackoverflow.com/a/62548305/9695286. In console.log it logs the object. But it will only retrieve and display all properties when you expand object values. – Karan

I will repost this answer from Karan as a solution.