# Jquery Json value doesnt change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am serializing a form and trying to change some values in this object but it never changes.
So I used a `test` variable for check this and when I am monitoring, this isnt changes too.

```
 var invoice = _$form.serializeFormToObject();
        var test = { ContainerNumber: "TEST" };
        var collectedContainerNumbers = JSON.parse(invoice.CollectedContainerNumbers);//["ABCD 123456-7","DEFK 231120-0","DNME 222222-2","DNME 321321-3","MACA 010220-2","OKLS 121212-1","TEST 000000-0","TeSt 123456-1","TeSt 123456-6","TeSt 123456-7","TEST 131313-1","TEST 150150-0","TEST 181818-1","TEST 222222-7","TEST 231114-1","TEST 232223-3","TEST 245680-2","TEST 333333-3","TEST 357913-5","TEST 444444-4","TEST 828282-8","TEST 999999-9"] 
        $.each(collectedContainerNumbers, function (index, value) {
            invoice.LogisticFileId = '';
            test.ContainerNumber = value;
            console.log(test);
        });
```

It is a `console` result. I am seeing a thing like a title and it is changing but content isnt changing.

[image: console result]

It looks like very simple but I don't understand the mistake that I am making.

Comment: Hi @Ender Kaya  open this link and I think it will solve your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318501/how-to-update-json-object-value-dynamically-in-jquery

Comment: hi @RajenderKumar it is not working for me because serialized form object is not using with forEach method.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a4bv5yzd/) ?

Comment: @Swati same but little difference. i mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kdb5cqzt/)
I want to use all values in array but original code isnt simple like that. invoice object has a lot of properties. I want to change just one of them and post to other method.

Comment: can you update your question with excepted output ? Also, proper json structure .

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62548305/9695286, you might be able to understand why console is showing such results but your actual object would be correct.

Comment: @Karan it is not related with this i think because my actual object isnt correcy but thank you.

Comment: Try with `console.log(JSON.stringify(test))` & check check what output you got on console.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** you will need an `array` instead of object to send all values to backend. Try converting your `test` object as an `array` like below.

```
var invoice = _$form.serializeFormToObject();
var test = []; // declare test as an array.
collectedContainerNumbers = JSON.parse(invoice.CollectedContainerNumbers);
$.each(collectedContainerNumbers, function (index, value) {
    invoice.LogisticFileId = '';
    test.push({ContainerNumber = value}); // push value in an array
    console.log(test);
});
```

---

Try this thing in console it might solve your confusion. Add an `object` like `let test = { ContainerNumber: 'ABCD 123456-7' }`. Then log it in console. **Do not expand right now**. Now change the value of `test.ContainerNumber = 'TEST 000000-0';`. Now log the object & expand both logs. In first log also when you expand it will display `{ ContainerNumber = 'TEST 000000-0' }`. as it is fetching current values when we **expand**.

You can also log `ContainerNumber` and check what exactly values hold by `test.ContainerNumber`. Like in below snippet. It will show you when you do `console.log(test.ContainerNumber);` first time it will show `ABCD 123456-7` and second time it will show `TEST 000000-0` which is as `expected`.

Try with below like. `1.` **Open console of browser**. `2.` Click on Run Code Snippet. `3.` Expand object in console.

```js
let test = { ContainerNumber: 'ABCD 123456-7' };
console.log(test);
console.log(test.ContainerNumber); // Output "ABCD 123456-7"

test.ContainerNumber = 'TEST 000000-0';

console.log(test);
console.log(test.ContainerNumber); // Output "TEST 000000-0"
```

```html
Check browser console.
```

Comment: you can be right but when i am posting object to backend, i am seeing same value everytime. how can i use different value?